# python request with authentication access token

Tags: python, rest, api, access-token

I am trying to get an API query into python. The command line

curl -X POST https://xxxx.com/api/auth/refreshToken   -d  access_token

it will give output in text string.access_tokenis a hexadecimal variable that remains constant throughout. I would like to make this call from python so that I can loop through different ids and analyze the output. Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests` library https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Maybe something like this :

```
response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

Then you can utilise the response and process it

Comment: how to add access token in your requests.post(..)??